# Route directions for driving mode

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm trying to implement a route direction for the points I have on my map, for doing that I'm using Polyline, the problem is, I managed to connect 2 points of the map, but I have an array of LatLng with 8 points, how would I connect all the points?:

```
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        setContentView(R.layout.maps);


        ArrayList<LatLng> coordList = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
        ArrayList<String> nomes = new ArrayList<String>();
        try {

            Bundle parametros = getIntent().getExtras();
            rm_IdViagem = parametros.getString("id_viagem");

            Repositorio ca = new Repositorio(this);
            mViagemModel = ca.getViagemPorId(Integer.valueOf(rm_IdViagem));

            Repositorio cl = new Repositorio(this);
            mClienteModel = cl.getClientesViagem(Integer.valueOf(rm_IdViagem));


            if(mClienteModel != null) {

                for (int i = 0; i < mClienteModel.size(); i++) {


                    Repositorio mRepositorio = new Repositorio(this);
                    mEnderecoModel = mRepositorio.getListaEnderecosDoCliente(Integer.valueOf(mClienteModel.get(i).getClientes_id()));


                    for (int j = 0; j < mEnderecoModel.size(); j++) {
                        // Loading map
                        initilizeMap();
                        // Changing map type
                        googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
                        // googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
                        // googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
                        // googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);
                        // googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NONE);

                        // Showing / hiding your current location
                        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

                        // Enable / Disable zooming controls
                        googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);

                        // Enable / Disable my location button
                        googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);

                        // Enable / Disable Compass icon
                        googleMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);

                        // Enable / Disable Rotate gesture
                        googleMap.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(true);

                        // Enable / Disable zooming functionality
                        googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);


                        final float latitude = Float.parseFloat(mEnderecoModel.get(j).getLatitude());
                        final float longitude = Float.parseFloat(mEnderecoModel.get(j).getLongitude());



                        nomes.add(mClienteModel.get(i).getNome());


                        coordList.add(new LatLng(latitude, longitude));

                        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(latitude, longitude), 5));



                        mClusterManager = new ClusterManager<MyItem>(MapaViagem.this, googleMap);


                        mClusterManager.setRenderer(new MyClusterRenderer(MapaViagem.this, googleMap, mClusterManager));

                        googleMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(mClusterManager);
                        googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(mClusterManager);

                        //mClusterManager.setAlgorithm(new GridBasedAlgorithm<MyItem>());




                        addItems(coordList, nomes);


                        mClusterManager.cluster();





                }


            }
        }


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


public class MyClusterRenderer extends DefaultClusterRenderer<MyItem> {

    public MyClusterRenderer(Context context, GoogleMap map,
                             ClusterManager<MyItem> clusterManager) {
        super(context, map, clusterManager);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBeforeClusterItemRendered(MyItem item, MarkerOptions markerOptions) {
        super.onBeforeClusterItemRendered(item, markerOptions);

        markerOptions.title(String.valueOf(item.getName()));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onClusterItemRendered(MyItem clusterItem, Marker marker) {
        super.onClusterItemRendered(clusterItem, marker);



        //here you have access to the marker itself
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean shouldRenderAsCluster(Cluster<MyItem> cluster) {
        return cluster.getSize() > 1;
    }



}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this example. This will help you to find solution.
http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/drawing-driving-route-directions-between-two-locations-using-google-directions-in-google-map-android-api-v2/

Comment: thank you it worked, but it connects only 2 points of the map, I have 8, how would I connect all the points? I've updated my question